# Returning error codes from a method

Tags: java, oop, return-type

I'd like to ask something confuses me a lot. Here is the scenario, lets say I have a method `preparePayload` that takes some argument like `messageType`, `destAddr` etc. The duty of method is construct a fully payload (with headers, prefixes etc). Here is the problem, I want to return `statusCode` (which is enum, like `STATUS_OK`,`STATUS_INVALID_DEST`, `STATUS_INVALID_MSG_TYPE` etc.), and than respect to return status I'd like to implement my logic. But if there is no error (`STATUS_OK`), I need the prepared payload to move on. So my method should return eighter payload or status code.

In C language, simply sending payload buffer address as an argument to preparePayload method solves the problem perfectly. When the method returns, simply reading payload from the buffer address and moving on the application works. How can I implement this kind of logic in Java?

In addition, `preparePayload` method is just an example I gave, so the methods I implemented may return `String`, `int[]`, some class object that I wrote etc. I mean, the type of object that method should return in success case may vary.

Any suggestion will very welcome.

Comment: I would suggest to throw an exception like `InvalidDestException` catch this exception and translate to the code.

Comment: In java you can't return different types unless you want to return like... `Object`.

Comment: You shall not use error codes in Java. Use Exception instead. If you really need error codes, create a wrapper class such as `ResponseWrapper` which contains a field for the status code and another field for the payload.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle : I think it is a best practice to throw exception than codes in any language. Quoting this from `Clean Code - Robert C Martin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides changing to exceptions, there is one more hackish way to allow for "input/output" parameters, like:

```
public ResultEnum preparePayLoad(List<PayLoad> toPrepare, ... other args) {
...
  PayLoad newThing = ...
...
  toPrepare.add(newThing);
  return someEnum;
}
```

So, you *could* use such an approach to "emulate" the "C style"; but the more Java/OO would be

```
public PayLoad preparePayLoad(args) {
...
  PayLoad newThing = ...
...
  return newThing;
}
```

and to throw (checked or unchecked) exceptions for error situations.

Comment: So I see, throwing an exception is the most suitable way for Java/OO concept.  The reason that I want to write application more C style is I want to see quickly the possible returns from a method. Anyway, I will stick to throwing exception design. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The correct idiom in Java is to throw a checked exception (some will say unchecked is better, there is a slight controversy here).

The three important mechanisms you get is:

- automatic propagation of error codes up the stack. If you do not handle some type of error in your code (don't check for it), it will get propagated up as an exception - you don't need layered checks (and avoid an error of returning an invalid result, quite common in C),
- exceptions work as an "alternate return type", ensuring type safety for both correct results and the error messages (which are full objects - and can contain any number of useful information besides the code)
- checked exceptions allow the compiler to check if all the important error statuses are handled in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, a wrapper, for example:

```
public class Result {
    public enum Status {
        STATUS_OK, STATUS_INVALID_DEST, STATUS_INVALID_MSG_TYPE
    }

    Status status;
    String payload;
}
```

that will be returned by your method `preparePayload`. Then, when you call your method, you can do it like this:

```
Result result = preparePayload(args);
//better will be a switch with case for each possible status
if (result.state == Result.State.STATUS_OK)
    //do what you want with payload
    System.out.println(result.payload);
else
    return;
```